# Is it impossible to match a value outside a fold's closure?

Tags: rust

I have these variables and I want to count how many times `c` appears in `s`.

```
let c = 2;
let s = vec![1, 2, 5, 2, 4, 2, 7];
```

Folding with a closure that uses an `if` expression compiles and works fine:

```
let r1 = s.iter().fold(0, |a, &x| a + if x == c { 1 } else { 0 });
```

However, if I want to use a `match` like

```
let r2 = s.iter().fold(0, |a, &x| a + match x { c => 1, _ => 0 });
```

the compiler complains with an unreachable pattern error message:

```
22 |     let r2 = s.iter().fold(0, |a, &x| a + match x { c => 1, _ => 0 });
   |                                                                 ^ this is an unreachable pattern
```

Is it really impossible to do it this way?

Comment: Your question is answered in the linked thread. But I would write your code as: `s.iter().filter(|&e| e == c).count()` :)